# make RGBA images to see edges from image in bottom

Tags: gimp, transparency, rgb

I have a panorama of mountains and photo, I want to place photo on panorama but I need to see (only) edges of mountains from panorama in my photo on top. So everything has to be invisible besides edges in photo.
Should I make photo on top partly transparent or can I do it by changing A value if images are RGBA?
Or if there is some tutorial for some photo editor (Gimp, etc.) but I hasn't found anything. 
My En is bad so there are links to images and you will see what I want to do.
[panorama](http://oi65.tinypic.com/xbzvhk.jpg)
[photo](http://oi65.tinypic.com/29kvuvp.jpg)
Thank you in advice, appreciate that.